# how can i fix (Unit etcd.service does not exist) this

Tags: ms-forms

## i try to access service apache2 status but i can not because of    (Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; preset: disabled)

```
 Active: inactive (dead)        **this**
```

i am tying to access msfvenom and if any one know the solution help me